# C# Find the greatest value on each line of the matrix and assign to array

Tags: arrays, matrix

C# Find the greatest value on each line of the matrix and assign to array.

Example:
We have a matrix like that.

```
1 2 3
4 5 9
3 6 7
```

Result: 3 9 7

How can i do that?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please provide a [mcve] so that we can help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the matrix `Mat` is stored in a 2-dimensional array of type `int[,]`, this can be done as follows.

```
var RowMaxima
    = new int[]{ Int32.MinValue, Int32.MinValue, Int32.MinValue };

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for  int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        RowMaxima[i] = Math.Min(RowMaxima[i], Mat[i,j]);
    }
}
```

If the data type containing the matrix is different or the dimensions are different from `3`, the implementation above has to be modified; perhaps it would be possible to use Linq.